# I cannot navigate to the else part of if--else loop in my selenium webdriver script

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, if-statement

I have a selenium Webdriver script that has if else loops. When I execute the script, the code always stops at the first if condition and does not move to the else part at all. And then i get an Exception as the if condition is false.
Is there any way out to work around the looping part in selenium web driver? I am using C# for coding.
Thanks in Advance.

Following is the looping structure i have used in my script:

```
    if (driver.FindElement(By.Id("ctl00_ContentMain_Label_Error")).Text.Contains("The username is already registered with Current Brand"))
{
    //take a screen shot
}

else if (driver.FindElement(By.Id("ctl00_Label_WelcomeMessage")).Text == "You are not currently signed in")
{
    //take a screen shot
}
else if (driver.FindElement(By.Id("ctl00_ContentLeftNav_UserNavBar_MenuItemLogOut")).Text == "Log Out")
{

//take a screenshot
}
```

Comment: Got any code to show us?

Answer (score 0):

Actually in the posted code you tried to compare the text which is retrieved from `driver.FindElement(By.Id("ctl00_Label_WelcomeMessage")).Text` and your `own text`.

The text which you got from the code returns a `String` data type. So, you can compare the String data type using the String manipulation concept. Using `equals`,`equalsIgnoreCase`,`contains` etc...

**Try this:**

```
 else if (driver.FindElement(By.Id("ctl00_Label_WelcomeMessage")).Text.equals("You are not currently signed in"))
{
//take a screen shot
}
```

instead of

```
else if (driver.FindElement(By.Id("ctl00_Label_WelcomeMessage")).Text == "You are not currently signed in")
{
//take a screen shot
}
```